# c# saving textbox.text to txt file. txt file doesn't recognize end of line character

Tags: c#, text, textbox, logging, text-files

I have the following code:

```
void AppendText(string txt)
{
    txt = txt + "\r\n";
    Textbox1.AppendText(txt);
    Textbox1.Select(Textbox1.Text.Length,0);
}

//....

void someFunction()
{
    //...
    string log = @"C:\log.txt";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(log, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.Write(Textbox1.Text);
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

The problem is in Textbox1.Text field in the form, "\r\n" works fine, but when I copy the Textbox1.Text to log.txt, the log.txt doesn't have new line where it's supposed to be. Instead there's a strange charater like this "[]" where "\r\n" is. I think problem lies in the sw.Write(tbox.text) right? But I don't know how to fix it. Could anyone give me a hand? Help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try Environment.Newline, might help.

Comment: You ought to use `Environment.NewLine` anyway.

Comment: As Anders suggested, replace your \r\n with Environment.NewLine and everything should work.

Comment: why don't you use the sw.WriteLine method instead. Drop the whole /n/r , as the method will put it in for you

Comment: @Anders Holmström and Mr. Disappointment: When you look at the Environment.NewLine code you will see that it's hardcoded: return "\r\n";. So.. the result is a same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this.

```
string log = @"C:\log.txt";     
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(log, FileMode.Create))     
{
     using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
     {
         foreach(string line in Textbox1.Lines)
             sw.Write(line+sw.NewLine);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the Textbox creates unicode characters (two bytes per character). 
In what format are you reading the data? ASCII unicode UTF?

If I remember correctly /n/r is an old trick to write a newline character to the string but in what format and what does it mean? Environment.Newline is much better and would work on windows mobile/unix builds too.

I usually create a class level variable called br with environment.newline as its content, creates much shorter code.

Comment: yeah, basically the textbox1.text is only a string when I used the /r/n. But with S.P suggestion I could write a new line in text file with each line in textbox.text. Anyway thanks for your time for answering. I'll try to use your suggestion in my next project. Thanks again Barfieldmv.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Just add `sw.Close();` after `sw.Write(Textbox1.Text);`